# sort variables my own way in R

Tags: r, sorting

I'd like to sort a categorical variable my own way. I have grouped my dataset into categories like "1-5","6-10","11-20" .... ">251" and so forth. If plot the variables or display them in a table the sequence of the legend respectively the sequence in the label is "messed up".

This is not surprising since R does not know that these unordered variables are ordered in fact. Is there a way to attach a manually defined sequence to them?

thx for any suggestions in advance!

Comment: Please can you provide some sample (minimal, reproducible) code, so that we can see exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I agree, the answer to your question was already given when you phrased it a little differently earlier.  The answer is still the same, cut().

Comment: I don't think cut() is the answer to the more general question of reordering factors. My 2c below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Categorical variables are stored as (or converted to be) `factor`s when you plot them.  The order they appear in the plot depends upon the levels of the factor.

You likely want to use `cut` to create your groups. e.g.

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = runif(100, 1, 256))
dfr$groups <- cut(dfr$x, seq(1, 256, 5))
```

This problem is also very similar to [another recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253641/how-to-change-the-order-of-a-discrete-x-scale-in-ggplot).

Comment: In fact, this advice seems to be just what rcs told you for your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288361/create-size-categories-without-nested-ifelse-in-r

Comment: yup, you´re right. obviously I need to take a closer look to that cut function. Just used ifelse so far... thx for pointing it out. Besides, I am still interested in re-arranging the order once I set it the wrong way...

Comment: cut() will allow you to set order.  If you need further control the factor() allows you to set order as well.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to specify a different order for a factor manually (tedious, but sometimes necessary) here is what I do:

```
> ## a factor
> x <- factor(letters[1:3])
> ## write out levels with dput
> dput(levels(x))
c("a", "b", "c")
> ## copy, paste, modify and use factor again. e.g.
> x <- factor(x, levels=c("b", "a", "c"))
> x
[1] a b c
Levels: b a c
```

Answer (score -1):

I like using `split` for that sort of thing.

> vect = runif(10)
>
> vect.categories = c(rep(LETTERS[1],5),rep(LETTERS[2],3),rep(LETTERS[5],2))
>
> category.list =split(vect,vect.categories)
>
> ....

May not be related, but thought I'd offer the suggestion.