# Splitting a continuous variable into equal sized groups

Tags: r, variables, split, continuous

I need to split/divide up a continuous variable into 3 equal sized groups.

Example data frame:

```
das <- data.frame(anim = 1:15,
                  wt = c(181,179,180.5,201,201.5,245,246.4,
                         189.3,301,354,369,205,199,394,231.3))
```

After being cut up (according to the value of `wt`), I would need to have the 3 classes under the new variable `wt2` like this:

```
> das 
   anim    wt wt2
1     1 181.0   1
2     2 179.0   1
3     3 180.5   1
4     4 201.0   2
5     5 201.5   2
6     6 245.0   2
7     7 246.4   3
8     8 189.3   1
9     9 301.0   3
10   10 354.0   3
11   11 369.0   3
12   12 205.0   2
13   13 199.0   1
14   14 394.0   3
15   15 231.3   2
```

This would be applied to a large data set.

Comment: See eg : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915916/divide-a-range-of-values-in-bins-of-equal-length-cut-vs-cut2 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647639/create-categorical-variable-in-r-based-on-range , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570293/r-adding-column-which-contains-bin-value-of-another-column , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161055/binning-data-finding-results-by-group-and-plotting-using-r , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731116/equal-frequency-discretization-in-r , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288361/create-size-categories-without-nested-ifelse-in-r , ...

Comment: Are you sure that the answer by @Ben Bolker is not the correct one? You specify that you want equal sized groups.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

try this:

```
split(das, cut(das$anim, 3))
```

if you want to split based on the value of `wt`, then

```
library(Hmisc) # cut2
split(das, cut2(das$wt, g=3))
```

anyway, you can do that by combining `cut`, `cut2` and `split`.

**UPDATED**

if you want a group index as an additional column, then

```
das$group <- cut(das$anim, 3)
```

if the column should be index like 1, 2, ..., then

```
das$group <- as.numeric(cut(das$anim, 3))
```

**UPDATED AGAIN**

try this:

```
> das$wt2 <- as.numeric(cut2(das$wt, g=3))
> das
   anim    wt wt2
1     1 181.0   1
2     2 179.0   1
3     3 180.5   1
4     4 201.0   2
5     5 201.5   2
6     6 245.0   2
7     7 246.4   3
8     8 189.3   1
9     9 301.0   3
10   10 354.0   3
11   11 369.0   3
12   12 205.0   2
13   13 199.0   1
14   14 394.0   3
15   15 231.3   2
```

Comment: You can remove the as.numeric and use `cut(das$anim, 3, labels=FALSE)`

Comment: This should be updated so it is clear that it is different from the answer by @Ben below. I mistakenly used this code in the belief that it would divide the observations evenly.

Comment: are you sure that the `Hmisc::cut2()` solution doesn't?  Can you give a small example where it doesn't?

Comment: Confusing to me why this is the accepted answer, when the question specifically says "equal sized groups", which `cut()` doesn't achieve.

Answer (score 78):

Or see `cut_number` from the `ggplot2` package, e.g.

```
das$wt_2 <- as.numeric(cut_number(das$wt,3))
```

Note that `cut(...,3)` divides the range of the original data into three ranges of equal lengths; it doesn't necessarily result in the same number of *observations* per group if the data are unevenly distributed (you can replicate what `cut_number` does by using `quantile` appropriately, but it's a nice convenience function).  On the other hand, `Hmisc::cut2()` using the `g=` argument *does* split by quantiles, so is more or less equivalent to `ggplot2::cut_number`.  I might have thought that something like `cut_number` would have made its way into `dplyr` by so far, but [as far as I can tell it hasn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163567/r-dplyr-categorize-numeric-variable-with-mutate).

Comment: This should be best answer, wish I had seen this first...!

Answer (score 11):

If you want to split into 3 equally distributed groups, the answer is the same as [Ben Bolker's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7965876/6713793) - use `ggplot2::cut_number()`. For sake of completion here are the 3 methods of converting continuous to categorical (binning).

- `cut_number()`: Makes n groups with (approximately) equal numbers of observation
- `cut_interval()`: Makes n groups with equal range
- `cut_width()`: Makes groups of width

My go-to is `cut_number()` because this uses evenly spaced quantiles for binning observations. Here's an example with skewed data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

skewed_tbl <- tibble(
    counts = c(1:100, 1:50, 1:20, rep(1:10, 3), 
               rep(1:5, 5), rep(1:2, 10), rep(1, 20))
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        counts_cut_number   = cut_number(counts, n = 4),
        counts_cut_interval = cut_interval(counts, n = 4),
        counts_cut_width    = cut_width(counts, width = 25)
        ) 

# Data
skewed_tbl
#> # A tibble: 265 x 4
#>    counts counts_cut_number counts_cut_interval counts_cut_width
#>     <dbl> <fct>             <fct>               <fct>           
#>  1      1 [1,3]             [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#>  2      2 [1,3]             [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#>  3      3 [1,3]             [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#>  4      4 (3,13]            [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#>  5      5 (3,13]            [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#>  6      6 (3,13]            [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#>  7      7 (3,13]            [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#>  8      8 (3,13]            [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#>  9      9 (3,13]            [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#> 10     10 (3,13]            [1,25.8]            [-12.5,12.5]    
#> # ... with 255 more rows

summary(skewed_tbl$counts)
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>    1.00    3.00   13.00   25.75   42.00  100.00

# Histogram showing skew
skewed_tbl %>%
    ggplot(aes(counts)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 30)
```

[image]

```r
# cut_number() evenly distributes observations into bins by quantile
skewed_tbl %>%
    ggplot(aes(counts_cut_number)) +
    geom_bar()
```

[image]

```r
# cut_interval() evenly splits the interval across the range
skewed_tbl %>%
    ggplot(aes(counts_cut_interval)) +
    geom_bar()
```

[image]

```r
# cut_width() uses the width = 25 to create bins that are 25 in width
skewed_tbl %>%
    ggplot(aes(counts_cut_width)) +
    geom_bar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 10):

Here's another solution using the `bin_data()` function from the [mltools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mltools/index.html) package.

```
library(mltools)

# Resulting bins have an equal number of observations in each group
das[, "wt2"] <- bin_data(das$wt, bins=3, binType = "quantile")

# Resulting bins are equally spaced from min to max
das[, "wt3"] <- bin_data(das$wt, bins=3, binType = "explicit")

# Or if you'd rather define the bins yourself
das[, "wt4"] <- bin_data(das$wt, bins=c(-Inf, 250, 322, Inf), binType = "explicit")

das
   anim    wt                                  wt2                                  wt3         wt4
1     1 181.0              [179, 200.333333333333)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
2     2 179.0              [179, 200.333333333333)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
3     3 180.5              [179, 200.333333333333)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
4     4 201.0 [200.333333333333, 245.466666666667)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
5     5 201.5 [200.333333333333, 245.466666666667)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
6     6 245.0 [200.333333333333, 245.466666666667)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
7     7 246.4              [245.466666666667, 394]              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
8     8 189.3              [179, 200.333333333333)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
9     9 301.0              [245.466666666667, 394] [250.666666666667, 322.333333333333)  [250, 322)
10   10 354.0              [245.466666666667, 394]              [322.333333333333, 394]  [322, Inf]
11   11 369.0              [245.466666666667, 394]              [322.333333333333, 394]  [322, Inf]
12   12 205.0 [200.333333333333, 245.466666666667)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
13   13 199.0              [179, 200.333333333333)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
14   14 394.0              [245.466666666667, 394]              [322.333333333333, 394]  [322, Inf]
15   15 231.3 [200.333333333333, 245.466666666667)              [179, 250.666666666667) [-Inf, 250)
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternative **without** using cut2.

```
das$wt2 <- as.factor( as.numeric( cut(das$wt,3)))
```

or

```
das$wt2 <- as.factor( cut(das$wt,3, labels=F))
```

As pointed out by @ben-bolker this splits into equal-widths rather occupancy. 
I think that using `quantiles` one can approximate equal-occupancy

```
x = rnorm(10)
x
 [1] -0.1074316  0.6690681 -1.7168853  0.5144931  1.6460280  0.7014368
 [7]  1.1170587 -0.8503069  0.4462932 -0.1089427
bin = 3 #for 1/3 rd, 4 for 1/4, 100 for 1/100th etc
xx = cut(x, quantile(x, breaks=1/bin*c(1:bin)), labels=F, include.lowest=T)
table(xx)
1 2 3 4
3 2 2 3
```

Comment: I think this splits into equal-width rather than equal-occupancy bins ?

Answer (score 7):

`ntile` from `dplyr` now does this but behaves weirdly with `NA`'s.

I've used similar code in the following function that works in base R and does the equivalent of the `cut2` solution above:

```
ntile_ <- function(x, n) {
    b <- x[!is.na(x)]
    q <- floor((n * (rank(b, ties.method = "first") - 1)/length(b)) + 1)
    d <- rep(NA, length(x))
    d[!is.na(x)] <- q
    return(d)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`cut`, when not given explicit break points divides values into bins of same width, they won't contain an equal number of items in general:

```
x <- c(1:4,10)
lengths(split(x, cut(x, 2)))
# (0.991,5.5]    (5.5,10] 
#           4           1
```

`Hmisc::cut2` and `ggplot2::cut_number` use quantiles, which will usually create groups of same size (in term of number of elements) if the data is well spread and of decent size, it's not always the case however. `mltools::bin_data` can give different results but is also based on quantiles.

These functions don't always give neat results when the data contains a small number of distinct values :

```
x <- rep(c(1:20),c(15, 7, 10, 3, 9, 3, 4, 9, 3, 2,
                   23, 2, 4, 1, 1, 7, 18, 37, 6, 2))

table(x)
# x
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
# 15  7 10  3  9  3  4  9  3  2 23  2  4  1  1  7 18 37  6  2   

table(Hmisc::cut2(x, g=4))
# [ 1, 6) [ 6,12) [12,19) [19,20] 
#      44      44      70       8

table(ggplot2::cut_number(x, 4))
# [1,5]  (5,11] (11,18] (18,20] 
#    44      44      70       8

table(mltools::bin_data(x, bins=4, binType = "quantile"))
# [1, 5)  [5, 11) [11, 18) [18, 20] 
#     35       30       56       45
```

This is not clear if the optimal solution has been found here.

What is the *best* binning approach is a subjective matter, but one reasonable way to approach it is to look for the bins that minimize the variance around the expected bin size.

The function `smart_cut` from (my) package [`cutr`](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/cutr/) proposes such feature. It's computationally heavy though and should be reserved to cases where cut points and unique values are few (which happen to be usually the case where it matters).

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/cutr")
table(cutr::smart_cut(x, list(4, "balanced"), "g"))
# [1,6)  [6,12) [12,18) [18,20] 
# 44      44      33      45
```

We see the groups are much better balanced.

`"balanced"` in the call can in fact be replaced by a custom function to optimize or restrict the bins as desired if the method based on variance isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

`equal_freq` from `funModeling` takes a vector and the number of bins (based on equal frequency):

```
das <- data.frame(anim=1:15,
                  wt=c(181,179,180.5,201,201.5,245,246.4,
                       189.3,301,354,369,205,199,394,231.3))

das$wt_bin=funModeling::equal_freq(das$wt, 3)

table(das$wt_bin)

#[179,201) [201,246) [246,394] 
#        5         5         5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `bin` function with `method = "content"` from the `OneR` package for that:

```
library(OneR)
das$wt_2 <- as.numeric(bin(das$wt, nbins = 3, method = "content"))
das
##    anim    wt wt_2
## 1     1 181.0    1
## 2     2 179.0    1
## 3     3 180.5    1
## 4     4 201.0    2
## 5     5 201.5    2
## 6     6 245.0    2
## 7     7 246.4    3
## 8     8 189.3    1
## 9     9 301.0    3
## 10   10 354.0    3
## 11   11 369.0    3
## 12   12 205.0    2
## 13   13 199.0    1
## 14   14 394.0    3
## 15   15 231.3    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any extra package, 3 being the number of groups:

```
> findInterval(das$wt, unique(quantile(das$wt, seq(0, 1, length.out = 3 + 1))), rightmost.closed = TRUE)
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 1 3 3 3 2 1 3 2
```

You can speed up the quantile computation by using a representative sample of the values of interest. Double check the documentation of the `FindInterval` function.

Answer (score 0):

So, interestingly if you would like to cut the variable "wt", into sections with equal 3 sub-sections (i.e., 179-181, 181-183, etc); you could do this:

```
x<-table(as.matrix(cut(das$wt,breaks = ((max(das$wt)-min(das$wt))/3)),as.numeric(cut(das$wt,breaks = ((max(das$wt)-min(das$wt))/3)))))
```

Which gives the result, based on the dataset "das":

```
x
(179,182] (188,191] (197,200] (200,203] (203,206] (230,234] (243,246] 
    3         1         1         2         1         1         1 
(246,249] (300,303] (352,355] (367,370] (391,394] 
    1         1         1         1         1
```

(that digit 3 in codes is an arbitrary item which can be changed by your interest.)