# Recoding continuous variable into categorical with *specific" categories, in R using Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning, categorical-data

I found [this helpful answer to *almost* the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163567/categorize-numeric-variable-with-mutate), but it doesn't quite do what I need.

I have respondents' age, a continuous variable, and I'd like to recode it to categorical using tidyverse. The link above includes explanations of the functions `cut_number()`, `cut_interval()`, and `cut_width()`, but the reason those don't work for me is because **I'd like to recode into categories that I've already determined ahead of time**, namely, the ranges 18-34, 35-54, and 55+. None of those `cut` functions allow me to do this (or at least I didn't see how).

I was able to get my code to run without tidyverse, using:

```
data$age[data$"Age(Self-report)"<35] <- "18-34"
data$age[data$"Age(Self-report)">34 & data$"Age(Self-report)"<55] <- "35-54"
data$age[data$"Age(Self-report)">55] <- "55+"
```

but I'm trying to be consistent in my coding style and would like to learn how to do this in Tidyverse. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Those ggplot `cut_*` functions are just convenience wrappers around the base `cut` function. Have you tried that, setting the breaks yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach would make use of `dplyr::case_when` to recode the variable like so:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(age = case_when(
    `Age(Self-report)` < 35 ~ "18-34",
    `Age(Self-report)` > 34 & `Age(Self-report)` < 55 ~ "35-54",
    `Age(Self-report)` > 55 ~ "55+"
  ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In my fervor of posting my first question I forgot to include the "case_when" code that I tried using!  


`data_2 <- data_2 %>%`


  `mutate(age = case_when(`

    `"Age(Self-report)" %in% seq(from="18", to="34") ~ "18-34",`

    `"Age(Self-report)" %in% seq(from="35", to="54") ~ "35-54",`

    `"Age(Self-report)" %in% seq(from="55", to="90") ~ "55+"))`  


I couldn't figure out what was wrong, though. Looks like I was making it more complex than it needed it be, as usual! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @ChrisJ. That will not work, because you put the varname in double quotes which means your are checking whether the charcter string "Age(Self-report)" is part of the interval defined by "seq". When using awkward varname like yours (;, you have use backticks like I did. BTW: Have a look at `dplyr::between` if you want to check whether a number is in an interval. Dont's use it that often but good to know.

Comment: @ChrisJ Don’t forget to tick the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Hah yes I need to rename them, I think it's a carryover from our survey item names! But it's good to understand how the quotes work compared to the backticks, with bad variable names! :) Thanks again.