# Grouped ranking in R

Tags: r

I have a data with primary key and ratio values like the following

```
2.243164164
1.429242413
2.119270714
3.013427143
1.208634972
1.208634972
1.23657632
2.212136028
2.168583297
2.151961216
1.159886063
1.234106444
1.694206176
1.401425329
5.210125578
1.215267806
1.089189869
```

I want to add a rank column which groups these ratios in say 3 bins. Functionality similar to the sas code:

```
PROC RANK DATA = TAB1 GROUPS = &NUM_BINS
```

Comment: We can use `?cut`  and specify `breaks=3`

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: Yep @akrun solution is great: try `data.frame(Value=values,Bin=as.integer(cut(values,breaks=3)))`

Comment: I tried cut. However the number of observations in the bins are not equal. The expected output would be   Bin 1 (1.089189869
1.159886063
1.208634972
1.208634972
1.215267806
1.234106444
)                                 Bin 2 (1.23657632
1.401425329
1.429242413
1.694206176
2.119270714
2.151961216
)                       Bin3 (2.168583297
2.212136028
2.243164164
3.013427143
5.210125578
)   Basically sorted and grouped in bins with equal number of observations

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:
Convert your vector to data frame.
Create variable Rank:

```
test2$rank<-rank(test2$test)
> test2
   test    rank
1  2.243164 15.0
2  1.429242  9.0
3  2.119271 11.0
4  3.013427 16.0
5  1.208635  3.5
6  1.208635  3.5
7  1.236576  7.0
8  2.212136 14.0
9  2.168583 13.0
10 2.151961 12.0
11 1.159886  2.0
12 1.234106  6.0
13 1.694206 10.0
14 1.401425  8.0
15 5.210126 17.0
16 1.215268  5.0
17 1.089190  1.0
```

Define function to convert to percentile ranks and then define pr as that percentile.

```
percent.rank<-function(x) trunc(rank(x)/length(x)*100)
test3<-within(test2,pr<-percent.rank(rank))
```

Then I created bins on the fact you wanted 3 of them.

```
test3$bins <- cut(test3$pr, breaks=c(0,33,66,100), labels=c("0-33","34-66","66-100"))

       test    x rank  pr   bins
1  2.243164 15.0 15.0  88 66-100
2  1.429242  9.0  9.0  52  34-66
3  2.119271 11.0 11.0  64  34-66
4  3.013427 16.0 16.0  94 66-100
5  1.208635  3.5  3.5  20   0-33
6  1.208635  3.5  3.5  20   0-33
7  1.236576  7.0  7.0  41  34-66
8  2.212136 14.0 14.0  82 66-100
9  2.168583 13.0 13.0  76 66-100
10 2.151961 12.0 12.0  70 66-100
11 1.159886  2.0  2.0  11   0-33
12 1.234106  6.0  6.0  35  34-66
13 1.694206 10.0 10.0  58  34-66
14 1.401425  8.0  8.0  47  34-66
15 5.210126 17.0 17.0 100 66-100
16 1.215268  5.0  5.0  29   0-33
17 1.089190  1.0  1.0   5   0-33
```

That work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Almost late but given your data, we can use `ntile` from `dplyr` package to get equal sized groups:

```
df <- data.frame(values = c(2.243164164,
                   1.429242413,
                   2.119270714,
                   3.013427143,
                   1.208634972,
                   1.208634972,
                   1.23657632,
                   2.212136028,
                   2.168583297,
                   2.151961216,
                   1.159886063,
                   1.234106444,
                   1.694206176,
                   1.401425329,
                   5.210125578,
                   1.215267806,
                   1.089189869))
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  arrange(values) %>%
  mutate(rank = ntile(values, 3))
    
    
     values rank
1  1.089190    1
2  1.159886    1
3  1.208635    1
4  1.208635    1
5  1.215268    1
6  1.234106    1
7  1.236576    2
8  1.401425    2
9  1.429242    2
10 1.694206    2
11 2.119271    2
12 2.151961    2
13 2.168583    3
14 2.212136    3
15 2.243164    3
16 3.013427    3
17 5.210126    3
```

Or see `cut_number` from `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
df$rank2 <- cut_number(df$values, 3, labels = c(1:3))

     values rank rank2
1  1.089190    1     1
2  1.159886    1     1
3  1.208635    1     1
4  1.208635    1     1
5  1.215268    1     1
6  1.234106    1     1
7  1.236576    2     2
8  1.401425    2     2
9  1.429242    2     2
10 1.694206    2     2
11 2.119271    2     2
12 2.151961    2     3
13 2.168583    3     3
14 2.212136    3     3
15 2.243164    3     3
16 3.013427    3     3
17 5.210126    3     3
```

Because your sample consists of 17 numbers, one bin consists of 5 numbers while the others consist of 6 numbers. There are differences for row 12: `ntile` assigns 6 numbers to the first and second group, whereas `cut_number` assigns them to the first and third group.

```
> table(df$rank)
1 2 3 
6 6 5 

> table(df$rank2)
1 2 3 
6 5 6
```

See also here: [Splitting a continuous variable into equal sized groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104836/splitting-a-continuous-variable-into-equal-sized-groups)