# R function for grouped ranking of stock performance for time-series

Tags: r, loops, automation, time-series, ranking

I have monthly returns in long format. For each month I want to assign the companies into 10 groups (deciles) of equal size according to their performance.

My data sample looks the following (here in ascending order of value, which is the monthly return):

```
print(R4, n=10)
# A tibble: 1,125 x 5
# Groups:   year [3]
   company                       year month value mktvalue
   <chr>                        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 STIFEL FINANCIAL              1997     7 0.821     50.3
 2 RAYMOND JAMES FINL.           1997    10 0.833   1070. 
 3 CHARLES SCHWAB                1997     3 0.853   6250. 
 4 STATE STREET                  1997     3 0.863   6178. 
 5 STIFEL FINANCIAL              1996     7 0.871     31.6
 6 FRANKLIN RESOURCES            1997     3 0.872   7459. 
 7 BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY 'A'        1997     8 0.879  53857. 
 8 ALLIANCEBERNSTEIN HLDG. UNT.  1997     3 0.879   2257. 
 9 STATE STREET                  1997     8 0.890   8504. 
10 MORGAN STANLEY                1996     7 0.891   8764. 
# ... with 1,115 more rows
```

Because I want to assign ranks to the companies for each month, I first filtered for one month:

```
R5 <- R4 %>%
  filter(year == 1997, month == 12, !is.na(value)) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  mutate(rank = rank(value))
            
print(R5)
# A tibble: 13 x 6
# Groups:   year [1]
   company                       year month value mktvalue  rank
   <chr>                        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 FRANKLIN RESOURCES            1997    12 0.967  11505.      1
 2 STATE STREET                  1997    12 0.978   9250.      2
 3 JEFFERIES FINANCIAL GROUP     1997    12 0.998   2175.      3
 4 BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY 'A'        1997    12 1.02   55184.      4
 5 BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON       1997    12 1.08   21152.      5
 6 CHARLES SCHWAB                1997    12 1.09   10854.      6
 7 MORGAN STANLEY                1997    12 1.09   32712.      7
 8 RAYMOND JAMES FINL.           1997    12 1.11    1207.      8
 9 MGIC INVESTMENT               1997    12 1.14    7030.      9
10 ALLIANCEBERNSTEIN HLDG. UNT.  1997    12 1.15    3107.     10
11 AFFILIATED MANAGERS           1997    12 1.16     373.     11
12 RADIAN GP.                    1997    12 1.16    1284.     12
13 STIFEL FINANCIAL              1997    12 1.17      81.4    13
```

I tried the answer from this question to assign companies into groups:
[Grouped ranking in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253583/grouped-ranking-in-r)

**Please tell me if there is a smarter way to create the decile groups.**

```
percent.rank <- function(x) trunc(rank(x)/length(x)*100)
R6 <- within(R5, pr <- percent.rank(rank))
R6$decile <- cut(R6$pr, breaks = c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), labels = c(1:10))
    
print(R6)
# A tibble: 13 x 8
# Groups:   year [1]
   company                       year month value mktvalue  rank    pr decile
   <chr>                        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> 
 1 FRANKLIN RESOURCES            1997    12 0.967  11505.      1     7 1     
 2 STATE STREET                  1997    12 0.978   9250.      2    15 2     
 3 JEFFERIES FINANCIAL GROUP     1997    12 0.998   2175.      3    23 3     
 4 BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY 'A'        1997    12 1.02   55184.      4    30 3     
 5 BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON       1997    12 1.08   21152.      5    38 4     
 6 CHARLES SCHWAB                1997    12 1.09   10854.      6    46 5     
 7 MORGAN STANLEY                1997    12 1.09   32712.      7    53 6     
 8 RAYMOND JAMES FINL.           1997    12 1.11    1207.      8    61 7     
 9 MGIC INVESTMENT               1997    12 1.14    7030.      9    69 7     
10 ALLIANCEBERNSTEIN HLDG. UNT.  1997    12 1.15    3107.     10    76 8     
11 AFFILIATED MANAGERS           1997    12 1.16     373.     11    84 9     
12 RADIAN GP.                    1997    12 1.16    1284.     12    92 10    
13 STIFEL FINANCIAL              1997    12 1.17      81.4    13   100 10
```

So far I did this manually for one month. **How can I apply this for every month and year of my data frame without manually filtering?**
My whole data would go from Jan 1996 to Dec 2020. The groups/deciles must be of equal size and ranked according to the monthly performance (value). Is there any way of looping or another smart way?

**To reproduce my data:**

```
R4 <- data.frame(company = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", 
                              "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"), 
                  year = c(1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996,1996, 1996, 1996, 
                           1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997), 
                  month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
                  value = c(1.15999568000864, 0.983783783783784, 1.07692307692308, 1, 0.989795918367347, 
                            0.989690721649484, 1, 1.04166666666667, 0.99, 1.05050505050505, 1.07211538461538, 
                            1.01345291479821, 0.942477876106195, 1.06572769953052, 0.986784140969163, 
                            0.879464285714286, 1.11167512690355, 0.922374429223744, 1.15841584158416, 
                            1.18803418803419, 0.973018705035971, 1.10906058132519, 0.92,  1.00724637681159))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow exactly what you're trying to do, but given your data I was able to create a ranked grouping by `value` for each `month`/`year` combination with this:

```
library(dplyr)
R4 %>% 
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  mutate(rank = rank(value)) %>% 
  arrange(month, year, rank)
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 60 × 6
# Groups:   year, month [24]
   company                       year month value mktvalue  rank
   <fct>                        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ALLIANCEBERNSTEIN HLDG. UNT.  1996     1 0.984    1802.     1
 2 BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY 'A'        1996     1 0.994   37088.     2
 3 BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON       1996     1 1.05     9517.     3
 4 ALLIANCEBERNSTEIN HLDG. UNT.  1997     1 1.07     2307.     1
 5 BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON       1997     1 1.08    13652.     2
 6 BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON       1996     2 1.01    10488.     1
 7 ALLIANCEBERNSTEIN HLDG. UNT.  1996     2 1.08     1931.     2
 8 BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY 'A'        1996     2 1.11    39584.     3
 9 ALLIANCEBERNSTEIN HLDG. UNT.  1997     2 0.987    2441.     1
10 BANK OF NEW YORK MELLON       1997     2 1.06    15457.     2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, the data sample I provided for reproduction included only 3 firm names. I updated it. 
My problem is that I have hundreds of firms in each month and want to put them into 10 groups of equal size according to their performance to format portfolios. In each month I want to know "Which top 10% companies performed best and which bottom 10% companies performed worst?". In order to build the portfolios and track them in later months, I want to store the rank/group.

Comment: Anyway, this helped me to find a solution! By first grouping year and month before mutating the rank, I specified ranks just within one month. Then, I applied my "percent.rank - function" to put the ranked companies into deciles. This gave me 10 equal-sized groups of companies in each month. Thanks!