# splitting a continuous variable into groups of equal number of elements - return numeric vector from bin values

Tags: r

I have a continuous variable that I want to split into bins, returning a numeric vector (of length equal to my original vector) whose values relate to the values of the bins.  Each bin should have roughly the same number of elements.

This question: [splitting a continuous variable into equal sized groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104836/splitting-a-continuous-variable-into-equal-sized-groups) describes a number of techniques for related situations.  For instance, if I start with

```
x = c(1,5,3,12,5,6,7)
```

I can use `cut()` to get:

```
cut(x, 3, labels = FALSE)
[1] 1 2 1 3 2 2 2
```

This is undesirable because the values of the factor are just sequential integers, they have no direct relation to the underlying original values in my vector.

Another possibility is `cut2`: for instance:

```
library(Hmisc)
cut2(x, g = 3, levels.mean = TRUE)
[1] 3.5 3.5 3.5 9.5 3.5 6.0 9.5
```

This better because now the return values relate to the values of the bins.  It is still less than ideal though since:

- (a) it yields a factor which then needs to be converted to numeric (see, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information)), which is both slow and awkward code wise.
- (b) Ideally I'd like to be able to choose whether to use the top or bottom end points of the intervals, instead of just the means.

I know that there are also options using regex on the factors returns from `cut` or `cut2` to get the top or bottom points of the intervals.  These too seem overly cumbersome.

Is this just a situation that requires some not-so-elegant hacking?  Or, is there some easier functionality to accomplish this?

**My current best effort is as follows:**

```
MyDiscretize = function(x, N_Bins){
    f = cut2(x, g = N_Bins, levels.mean = TRUE)
    return(as.numeric(levels(f))[f])
}
```

My goal is to find something faster, more elegant, and easily adaptable to use either of the endpoints, rather than just the means.

---

**Edit:**

To clarify: my desired output would be:

- (a) an equivalent to what I can achieve right now in the example with `cut2` but without needing to convert the factor to numeric.
- (b) if possible, the ability to also easily chose to use either of the endpoints of the interval, instead of the midpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ave` like this:

Given:

```
x = c(1,5,3,12,5,6,7)
```

Mean:

```
ave(x,cut2(x,g = 3), FUN = mean)
[1] 3.5 3.5 3.5 9.5 3.5 6.0 9.5
```

Min:

```
ave(x,cut2(x,g = 3), FUN = min)
[1] 1 1 1 7 1 6 7
```

Max:

```
ave(x,cut2(x,g = 3), FUN = max)
[1]  5  5  5 12  5  6 12
```

Or standard deviation:

```
ave(x,cut2(x,g = 3), FUN = sd)
[1] 1.914854 1.914854 1.914854 3.535534 1.914854       NA 3.535534
```

Note the NA result for only one data point in interval.

Hope this is what you need.

NOTE:
Parameter g in `cut2` is number of quantile groups. Groups might not have the same amount of data points, and the intervals might not have the same length.
On the other hand, `cut` splits the interval into several of equal length.

Comment: Ok, thank you, this is helpful, both the function and the note.  I may have been sloppy in my terminology, - `cut2` is a way to get bins with *relatively* equal numbers of elements, right?

Comment: Not really, if you look at the result of `cut2` the first group contains four elements, the second only one and the last two.  Function `cut`does not guarantee that each group will have the same amount of elements.

Comment: If you want to have the same quantity of elements, you should order them and then separate them into equally sized groups.

Comment: Looking at the docs for `cut_number` from ggplot2, it looks like it *tries* for approximate equality, but doesn't guarantee it.  `cut2` isn't explicit one way or the other, but it may perhaps be much the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not much elegant, but should be efficient. Try this function:

```
myCut<-function(x,breaks,retValues=c("means","highs","lows")) {
    retValues<-match.arg(retValues)
    if (length(breaks)!=1) stop("breaks must be a single number")
    breaks<-as.integer(breaks)
    if (is.na(breaks)||breaks<2) stop("breaks must greater than or equal to 2") 
    intervals<-seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=breaks+1)
    bins<-findInterval(x,intervals,all.inside=TRUE)
    if (retValues=="means") return(rowMeans(cbind(intervals[-(breaks+1)],intervals[-1]))[bins])
    if (retValues=="highs") return(intervals[-1][bins]) 
    intervals[-(breaks+1)][bins]
}
x = c(1,5,3,12,5,6,7)
myCut(x,3)
#[1]  2.833333  6.500000  2.833333 10.166667  6.500000  6.500000  6.500000
myCut(x,3,"highs")
#[1]  4.666667  8.333333  4.666667 12.000000  8.333333  8.333333  8.333333
myCut(x,3,"lows")
#[1] 1.000000 4.666667 1.000000 8.333333 4.666667 4.666667 4.666667
```