# r cut function in r results consistency

Tags: r

Using the cut function in R:

```
as.numeric(cut( 1:6,4))
## [1] 1 1 2 3 4 4
```

Is there a way to get it to cut the value in largest chunks first so that

```
as.numeric(cut( 1:6,4))
```

would return

```
## [1] 1 1 2 2 3 4
```

instead? and,

```
table(as.numeric(cut( 1:7,4)))
```

would return

```
## [1] 2 2 2 1
```

instead of

```
## [1] 2 2 1 2
```

etc…

Comment: You can pass what ever `breaks=` you want based on your own rule (which isn't immediately clear from just two very specific examples). You can't change the default rule that `cut` uses however. Just create your own function that wraps cut with whatever you like.

Comment: It should chunk from start to end like in the example I gave

Comment: The way you use cut, equally spaced cut points are created, there is no "bigger chunk", what you might want it is equally sized groups : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104836/splitting-a-continuous-variable-into-equal-sized-groups . what you are asking for presents many edge cases though so we'd need much more comprehensive details and examples to help. Though you might want to look at dplyr::ntile