# R: create a new categorical variable from a categorical variable based on a continuous variable

Tags: r, variables, split, categories

I already had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104836/splitting-a-continuous-variable-into-equal-sized-groups), where the `cut` function is used. However, I haven't been able to come up with a clever solution given my situation.

First some example data that I currently have:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Category = LETTERS[1:20], 
  Nber_within_category = c(rep(1,8), rep(2,3), rep(6,2), rep(10,3), 30, 50, 77, 90)
)
```

I would like to make a third column that forms a new category based on the `Nber_within_category` column. In this example, how can I make e.g. `Category_new` such that in each category, the `Nber_within_category` is at least 5 with the constrain that if `Category` already has `Nber_within_category >= 5`, that the original category is taken.

So for example, it should look like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Category = LETTERS[1:20], 
  Nber_within_category = c(rep(1,8), rep(2,3), rep(6,2), rep(10,3), 30, 50, 77, 90),
  Category_new = c(rep('a',5), rep('b', 4), rep('c',2), LETTERS[12:20])
)
```

Comment: Keeping the original category when `Nber_within_category >= 5` is clear enough, but what was the logic behind the choice of categories for the other rows? I mean why would the first 5 rows - for example - have the same "new" category?

Comment: That's allowed to be random, as long as their sum (of `Nbrer_within_category`) is +/- 5. So I tried doing it with a `cumsum`, but didn't get to an answer using that. So, whether you take the first 5 as a new category, or the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, and 9th, does not matter for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but it works:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(tmp = floor((cumsum(Nber_within_category) - 1)/5)) %>% 
  mutate(new_category = ifelse(Nber_within_category >= 5,
                               Category,
                               letters[tmp+1]))
```

The line `floor((cumsum(Nber_within_category) - 1)/5)` is a way of categorising the cumsum with bins of size 5 (-1 to include the rows where the sum is exactly 5), and which I'm using as an index to get new categories for the rows where `Nber_within_category < 5`

It might be easier to understand how the column `tmp` is defined if you run :

```
x <- 1:100
data.frame(x, y = floor((x- 1)/5))
```

Comment: Clever solution, thanks for the additional explanation at the bottom!