# Is there an existing function in R that sorts a continuous variable into an EQUAL number of observations per group?

Tags: r, sorting, indexing

I have a 2319 row data frame `df`; I would like to sort the continuous variable `var` and split in into a specified number of groups with an *equal* (or as close as possible) number of observations per group. I have seen a similar post where `cut2()` from `Hmisc` was recommended, but it does not always provide an equal number of observations per group. For example, what I have using cut2()

```
df$Group <- as.numeric(cut2(df$var, g = 10))

var Group
1415 1
1004 1
1285 1
2099 2
2119 2
2427 4
...

table(df$Group)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
232 232 241 223 233 246 219 243 226 224
```

Has anyone used/written something that does not rely on the underlying distribution of the variable (e.g. `var`), but rather the number of observations in the data and number of groups specified? I do have non-unique values.

What I want is a more equal number of observations, for example:

```
table(df$Group)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
232 232 231 233 231 233 232 231 231 233
```

Comment: if you gave a [mcve] we could more easily test our answers and make sure they were what you wanted ...

Comment: Also, could you please rephrase your question as "how do I ... ?" rather than "is there an existing function that ... ?" It would be more on-topic for SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104836/splitting-a-continuous-variable-into-equal-sized-groups

Comment: This is not a duplicate question as the solution in that post was cut2() which does not result in an even number of obs per group (see my example above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut`/`cut2` and other function depends on the distribution of the data to create groups. If you want more or less equal number of observations one option would be to use `rep`.

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 10

df %>%
  arrange(var) %>%
  mutate(Group = cummax(rep(seq_len(n), each = n()/n, length.out = n())))
```

Comment: does this work properly with 2319 observations and 10 groups? (It might, but I wouldn't be surprised if you had to do something clever to make sure the rounding came out OK)

Comment: It does work ok with any number of rows due to `length.out = n()`. The only issue could be  that the last few values would repeat group = 1 again.

Comment: This is closer, though like you said the last few values (the largest values of var) get put back into group 1 with the smallest values so it will not work. It would work if those last values were placed in group 10.

Comment: @Aliv25 Can you try the updated answer with `cummax` so that the largest value stays in the last group.

Comment: Worked! Thanks @RonakShah